# How to automate a browser with the requests library (not selenium cause performance)

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, request, python-requests

#### Why I want to use the requests library, not Selenium

I know it's way more complicated than just using Selenium. I already have a working Selenium application for what I need. I also already disabled the images, proxy, ... for performance optimization. And I also know that Selenium can be headless. But it's still to slow.

#### What I need to do

The Problem is that I want to upload a bunch of images with some information on multiple websites. So I have like 200 .png files and each has a name, a description and so on. Even with the optimizations, it would take quite long using Selenium.

#### My current idea

My idea is to only send a post request on pages with a form so I don't need to request the HTML. I also have an idea how to click normal buttons (Just get the link and get this page (could also save this links so I don't even have to request the page with the button)).

#### The problem

The big problem is just JavaScript! How can I run JavaScript functions from a script file I, for example, got from the head. Or how can I run single commands of JavaScript?
I need to do all the things the browser would do if I click on buttons that have a JavaScript event bind to them. But I need to do it in Python. Do you know a good library for doing this? Or is it even possible directly in requests?

#### Exact things I need to do (I don't know how to do it)

-> I need to run JavaScript in python
-> I need to get a result of a JavaScript function as a var in python
-> I need to be able to render a JavaScript rendered webpage
-> I need to click on buttons with no link but a JavaScript function bind to the click
-> I need to compute information or changes on the images if they are normally computed by JavaScript and caused by the user clicking on something
**Hope you can help me! Thank you for your help!**

Comment: Could you please include some of your code in your question?

Comment: @Fozoro Not really. I could share the selenium code but I think this doesn't lead to the answer to the question. And I haven't started with coding the script that uses the request library. I could share the html/Javascript of one website.